# MtGox API Overview and explanation of steps required to create connection

Tags: mtgox, api, ios

I am trying to write a simple app that uses the Mt Gox. (bitcoin exchange) API.

It's very simple to use the price API it's just a http request that returns a .JSON string.

However now I want to do more with my app, I was thinking it would be good to be able to log into the users mtgox account and show their balance of bitcoin.

I have an API key (you can generate one on their site) but I'm finding it really hard to understand whats required to generate a connection and pull the balance.

Is there anyone who might be able to point me in the right direction?

I have researched quite a bit and turned up very little information - API Overview: https://bitbucket.org/nitrous/mtgox-api/overview

In the above link they have some python code, but i'm finding it difficult to translate into Objective C.

So if anyone can:

A. Give me a highlevel overview of the steps required to log in and get a bitcoin balance using the API.

B. Give me some pointers on how to turn their Python example into Objective C I would really appreciate it.

I understand to use the API I need to use this URL to Get my current balance    mtgox.com/api/0/getFunds.php -- however first I need to get a "nonce" parameter to the post data (which must be an ever-increasing interger, for example with PHP in 64bits: (int)(microtime(true)*1000000)) and two HTTP headers: Rest-Key (your key) nad Rest-Sign (a signature generated by doing a sha512-hmac on the POST data with the secret as key, encoded in base64).

I found this documentation: bitbucket.org/nitrous/mtgox-api/overview -- still not clear however, how to code in Objective C thanks

Comment: This is a badly titled question. Please give some kind of indication of what the question is about in the title.

Comment: Updated thanks. need to type more chars because of the silly limit where by you cannot just say thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Take a look at the Java [XChange](https://github.com/timmolter/XChange) project**

While it is not Objective C it will provide you with all the details you'll need to get your library off the ground including the HMAC authentication process and websockets.

You'll also find a range of other exchanges supported so you can implement those as well thus providing your application with a broader range of potential users since not everyone uses MtGox these days.

Comment: Yep, I'm very pleased with the way that XChange has shaped up. There's been a lot of good work done on it.

Comment: going to mark this as answered as yours is as close as I'll get!